# How to prepend a decremented number to a string in a loop?

Tags: php, loops, decrement

I am trying to make a triangular-shaped set of lines of decreasing numbers like this :

```
5
45
345
2345
12345
```

I tried this :

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
    {
        echo $j;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

But it is printing the low number first and appending increasing numbers like this :

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Comment: You have to start with i=5... Not 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop needs to count down instead of up.

You can either subtract the outer loop's variable from the limit to get the starting point and count down:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    for ($j = 5 - $i; $j > 0; $j--)
    {
        echo $j;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

or change the outer loop to count down from the limit as well.

```
for ($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--)
{
    for ($j = $i; $j >= 1; $j--)
    {
        echo $j;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its explanation

Comment: When you edit, you have a decrementing typo as well.

Comment: @mickmackusa I had a bunch of problems, can't believe the answer was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
$max = 5;

echo "<pre>";

for($line=0; $line<$max; $line++) {
    $min_this_line = $max-$line;
    for($num = $min_this_line; $num <= $max; $num++) {
        echo $num;
    }
    echo "\n";
}

echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
5
45
345
2345
12345
```

Comment: This straightforward answer is missing its explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would declare the `$peak` value, then use a `for()` loop to decrement the counter down to 1, and use `implode()` and `range()` to build the respective strings inside the loop.

This isn't going to outperform two `for()` loops, but for relatively small `$peak` values, no one is going to notice any performance hit.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KLo8j))

```
$peak = 5;

for ($i = $peak; $i; --$i) {
    echo implode(range($i, $peak)) , "\n";
}
```

or with two loops: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/neA54))

Decrement the outer loop and increment the inner loop.

```
$peak = 5;

for ($i = $peak; $i; --$i) {
    for ($n = $i; $n <= $peak; ++$n) {
        echo $n;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Both output:

```
5
45
345
2345
12345
```